# Flutter: Display local datetimes correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

let's say I have a `DateTime` object and I want to display it in the correct local format.

If I do the following on a **German** device I get this:

```
dateTime.toLocal().toString()
// Prints
2022-05-28 23:29:19.518
```

However, I would expect or desire more something like this for a **German** device: `28.5.2022 23:29:19`

I know that I can format the `DateTime` but that would just be hardcoding it for a certain `locale`.

Weirdly enough all the solutions that I found for this on StackOverflow are either hardcoding the format or only apply to Dart, not Flutter.

**What is the correct way to display a local `datetime` in Flutter?**

Comment: Why would answers that apply to Dart not also apply to Flutter?  See the [`DateFormat` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) where it discusses using `initializeDateFormatting` and about how certain "skeletons" honor formatting conventions for the locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and localise dates like

```
var format = DateFormat.yMd('ar');
var dateString = format.format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: I also had to call `initializeDateFormatting` in the `initState` method.  To get the correct `locale` I used `Platform.localeName`. `"ar"` is the arabic `locale`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the intl package which was mentioned here already, this has been working well for me so far:

```
DateFormat dateTimeFormat = DateFormat.jm(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());
DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(entity.syncDateTime);
dateTimeFormat.format(dt);
```

To get outputs which are not yet supported I, for example, concat a `ymd` formatted `DateTime` string with a `jm` formatted `DateTime` string.